# How can I make a reference variable for a function in Excel?

Tags: excel, function, variables, formula

Trying to make a variable work within a function. Here's how:
I've got an income tax calculator. It works perfect. I can also get the correct value if I were to use SUMPRODUCT (or even VLOOKUP if I use a cumulative table, nvm that for now though; just know that I've tried VLOOKUP as well).

The SUMPRODUCT formula goes like this:

`=SUMPRODUCT(A4:A10-A3:A9,E1-C4:C10,N(E1>C4:C10))`

I want to be able to replace E1 with "x" so that I can make a formula so `=Tax(E1)` will give me the same result as the SUMPRODUCT formula did.
Problem is I don't know how to use "x" as the variable.

Using `=LET(x, E1, SUMPRODUCT(A4:A10-A3:A9,x-C4:C10,N(x>C4:C10)))` does give the correct value. From here I want to turn that into a simpler formula that I can dynamically change "E1" to anything by the formula `=Tax(E1)` or any cell other than E1.

[Picture of table with SUMPRODUCT formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lck5u.png)

--------- EDIT ---------
I ended up looking into the SUMPRODUCT function and really finding out how that works and then Googling a bunch of VBA stuff. Ended up just making a VBA function that handles the whole thing. Here it is in case anyone ever needs it:

```
Dim Rate1 As Single
Dim Rate2 As Single
Dim Rate3 As Single
Dim Rate4 As Single
Dim Rate5 As Single
Dim Rate6 As Single
Dim Rate7 As Single

Dim Over1 As Single
Dim Over2 As Single
Dim Over3 As Single
Dim Over4 As Single
Dim Over5 As Single
Dim Over6 As Single
Dim Over7 As Single

Dim Amount1 As Single
Dim Amount2 As Single
Dim Amount3 As Single
Dim Amount4 As Single
Dim Amount5 As Single
Dim Amount6 As Single
Dim Amount7 As Single

Dim Tax1 As Single
Dim Tax2 As Single
Dim Tax3 As Single
Dim Tax4 As Single
Dim Tax5 As Single
Dim Tax6 As Single
Dim Tax7 As Single

Dim Final As Single




Function Tax(Value As Single)
    Rate1 = 0.1
    Rate2 = 0.02
    Rate3 = 0.1
    Rate4 = 0.02
    Rate5 = 0.08
    Rate6 = 0.03
    Rate7 = 0.02
    
    Over1 = 0
    Over2 = 9951
    Over3 = 40526
    Over4 = 86376
    Over5 = 164926
    Over6 = 209426
    Over7 = 523601
    
    Amount1 = Value - Over1
    If Amount1 > 0 Then
        Tax1 = Amount1 * Rate1
        Final = Tax1
        Amount2 = Value - Over2
    Else
        Amount2 = 0
    End If
    If Amount2 > 0 Then
        Tax2 = Amount2 * Rate2
        Final = Final + Tax2
        Amount3 = Value - Over3
    Else
        Amount3 = 0
    End If
    If Amount3 > 0 Then
        Tax3 = Amount3 * Rate3
        Final = Final + Tax3
        Amount4 = Value - Over4
    Else
        Amount4 = 0
    End If
    If Amount4 > 0 Then
        Tax4 = Amount4 * Rate4
        Final = Final + Tax4
        Amount5 = Value - Over5
    Else
        Amount5 = 0
    End If
    If Amount5 > 0 Then
        Tax5 = Amount5 * Rate5
        Final = Final + Tax5
        Amount6 = Value - Over6
    Else
        Amount6 = 0
    End If
    If Amount6 > 0 Then
        Tax6 = Amount6 * Rate6
        Final = Final + Tax6
        Amount7 = Value - Over7
    Else
        Amount7 = 0
    End If

    
    
    
    Tax = Value - Final
End Function
```

Comment: You can only do that if you have the LAMBDA function. Otherwise, you'll need a UDF.

Comment: You want it to always refer to a4:a10 etc and only change E1? then why not using =SUMPRODUCT($A$4:$A$10-$A$3:$A$9,E1-$C$4:$C$10,N(E1>$C$4:$C$10)) and lock all else in place?

Answer (score 0):

If you have Excel 365, you can now use a Lambda [General description](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/blog/lambda-the-ultimatae-excel-worksheet-function/)  [Examples](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/lambda-function-bd212d27-1cd1-4321-a34a-ccbf254b8b67) to define a function without VBA. In principle it would be almost the same as the Let:

```
=LAMBDA(x, SUMPRODUCT(Sheet1!A4:A10-Sheet1!A3:A9,x-Sheet1!C4:C10,N(x>Sheet1!C4:C10)))
```

but in practice you need to make the references absolute because otherwise the formula will change depending where you call it from:

```
=LAMBDA(x, SUMPRODUCT(Sheet1!$A$4:$A$10-Sheet1!$A$3:$A$9,x-Sheet1!$C$4:$C$10,N(x>Sheet1!$C$4:$C$10)))
```

This is how you define it in the Name Manager:

[image]

You can then simply put

```
=Tax(E1)
```

in any cell.

Note that you may need to be subscribed to the [Office Insider](https://insider.office.com/en-gb/) programme to have access to this function, as mentioned by @Jos Woolley.

Comment: You should probably amend "If you have Excel 365" to "If you have Excel 365 and are also subscribed to Office Insiders"

Comment: You're probably right, but different users seem to have different experiences with the roll-out of this.